# IOS simulator delays on loading new page in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm running a react native app on Xcode IOS simulator. in my case, i have two tabs in TabNavigation with ReactNavigation. When i change the tab, the simulator doesn't render the new tab. If i click on other tabs or even press **Command+D**, the new screen will load. It just need anything like refresh...

I will be thankful if anybody can help me

Comment: Without some code it will be difficult to assess the problem

Comment: @dentemm I think it's not a source dependent problem! my source code runs perfectly on physical android and iPad devices... but in iPhone simulator it has this problem

Comment: Ow okay, strange indeed... I never had any issues with the iOS sim. Do you notice this on all devices on the simulator or only when simulating a specific device? Ah and one more question: which react-navigation version are you using?

Comment: I used iPhone 6 and iPhone 8 and i have the same problem! i'm using react navigation 1.0.0-beta.13 with RN 0.49.3.  Thanks for your consideration... :)

Comment: A bit of research has lead me nowhere, but I think you best consider an upgrade to a more recent version of react-navigation. You could probably even upgrade to version 2.x without much if any breaking changes

Comment: anyway... thank you :)

Comment: Same issue here. It happens to me with two different projects, one using the latest react-navigation and RN, the other using older versions. It seems to be related to the Mac. In a 2011 MacBook 13'' the screen is not refreshed after navigating between tabs (pressing CMD+D twice forces a refresh, activating the Perf Monitor also fixes the issue but has to be done after every CMD+R, not a solution, but a workaround). In a 2018 MacBook Air it works perfectly.